# Tengo problemas al mostrar el jframe

Tags: java, jframe, mouselistener

El programa es sobre que en una ventana se muestre una imagen y que esa imagen siga el cursor del mouse también es que en una esquina del panel esta muestre las coordenadas donde se muestra la imagen, el problema llega al ejecutar el programa la ventana del jpanel se muestra en negro y con solo unos pequeños cuadros de color blanco tampoco me  no muestra ni la imagen ni las coordenadas que necesito.

```
package Main;


import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Evento extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener{

   //declaramos variables x, y que son las cordenadas del cursor
    int x,y;
    String Texto="";
    
    
    
    public Evento() {
                addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }
//creamos el jframe
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Evento MouseMoved");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.getContentPane().add(new Evento());
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,500);
       
     }
    //cargamos la imagen en este caso es de 67x67
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    ImageIcon imagen= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("compudos.png"));
    g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), x, y,67,67, null);
    Font fuente =new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,15);
    g.setFont(fuente);
    g.drawString(Texto, 20,400);
    
    }
   
    
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
//añadimos la coordenadas en las que va a estar el cursor 
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
x=(int)e.getPoint().getX();
y=(int)e.getPoint().getY();
        Texto="X: "+x+"   Y:  "+y;
repaint();

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Holaa, he probado tu código y aparece una ventana en negro, eclipse me tira error, diciendo que la ubicación de la imagen no existe, probé colocar una imagen mía y si funciono, solo que hay otro problema al mover el cursor, la imagen se dibuja una y otra vez, pintando todo el panel, por lo que las coordenadas se sobre pintan y no se entiende nada.

La solución: Lo que yo siempre hago es crear un JLabel para la imagen, y otro JLabel para las coordenadas, en el evento del mouse, ir moviendo la imagen y cambiando el texto al JLabel de las coordenadas.

Te muestro el error de que se repinta y te muestro otra imagen creado con los JLabel...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, como has cargado la imagen porque he cargado varias imagenes y no he solucionado por mas que cambie la imagen sigue el fondo asi :(

Comment: hola de nuevo, disculpa no he haber respondido antes, la manera en la que cargo la imagen es la siguiente, la imagen esta dentro del paquete:  imagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Evento.class.getClassLoader().getResource("pablo/stack/hamburguesaBlanco.png")));